# Error for clone() Method

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class F1 {
   public static void man(String[] args) {

      ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(4);

      a1.add(15);
      a1.add(30);
      a1.add(20);
      a1.add(18);

      ArrayList<Integer> a2 = a1.clone();

      for (Integer number : a2) {
         System.out.println("Number = " + number);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error?  How to you call the main() method?

Comment: I wasn't able to compile this until I cast `ArrayList<Integer> a2 = (ArrayList<Integer>) a1.clone();`  After that, it compiled and worked, although I'm not sure clone is the best approach to copying the arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `clone()` method does not return the same type.  It does, however, return a copy of the `ArrayList`; however, it is returned as a `java.lang.Object`.

In order to make the code function as expected, cast the `clone()` call return as an `ArrayList<Integer>` ie:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a2 = (ArrayList<Integer>) a1.clone();
```

Edit : "a1.clone()" instead of "a1.close()"

Answer (score 1):

ArrayList implements Cloneable, so you can clone that way.
But clone returns an Object, not an ArrayList, so you need the cast.
However, if you simply need to copy your ArrayList in a new instance, consider to do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(a1);
```

a2 will have the same elements of a1, but it is a different object.